# Не могу поключится к MySQL через PHP

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, docker

У меня возникла проблема. Я немогу поклюиться к MySQL с помощю php скрипта. Локалка поднята на докере. PHP и Mysql в отдельных контейнерах. Код подключения:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("172.22.0.4", "root", "password", "dostavka", '3306');

if (!$link) {
    echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "<br>Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "<br>Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Соединение с MySQL установлено!" . PHP_EOL;
echo "<br>Информация о сервере: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
```

Вывод:

```
Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL.
Код ошибки errno: 2002
Текст ошибки error: Connection refused
```

Логи:

```
php-fpm_1  | [18-Mar-2020 17:50:04] WARNING: [pool www] child 7 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /var/www/database.php on line 2"
php-fpm_1  | 172.22.0.4 -  18/Mar/2020:17:50:04 +0000 "GET /database.php" 200
nginx_1    | 2020/03/18 17:50:04 [error] 6#6: *25 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /var/www/database.php on line 2" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.22.0.1, server: magedk.local, request: "GET /database.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.22.0.3:9000", host: "magedk.local"
nginx_1    | 172.22.0.1 - - [18/Mar/2020:17:50:04 +0000] "GET /database.php HTTP/1.1" 200 174 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"
```

Comment: Похоже неправильно прописан хост.

Comment: Всем привет. Я много делал експерементов и просто использовал немного другой скрипт. Вот он - $link = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", 'root', 'password', 'dostavka');

Comment: теперь вроде норм, поменяли "172.22.0.4" на "172.22.0.1"

Comment: Перед тем я также вводил 127.0.0.1 , но оно не роботало. Когда заменил "mysqli_connect" на "new mysqli" код зароботал.